# Pulsating illuminated switch

Tags: electrical, switch, led

My LED illuminated switches are pulsating.Each switch runs to its own light, but they’re on the same breaker. They started pulsating a few days after I installed 2 new LED style fixtures. I uninstalled each fixture one-by-one and tried to determine if it was one or the other fixture causing the issue. It kept pulsing. Removed both fixtures and installed the old fixtures and the pulsing stopped. I installed the same style fixtures in another area of the home, and everything is steady. Are those fixtures bad?

Comment: Are these dimmer switches?

Comment: No, they’re not.

Comment: LED fixtures, bulbs and switches (dimmers especially) are a finicky bunch. You just have to experiment with combinations to find ones that will play nice with each other.

Comment: Are you sure those illuminated switches ar LED and not neon?  Does the problem disappear if you add *one* incandescent, keeping the rest LEDs?   (Most of the time when I say this, people think I am saying to change them all back to incandescent (wrong) permanently (wrong).  No, one only, and it's a diagnostic test.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be the non pulsing switches have additional loads on the circuit that help cancel the pulses.

A lighting engineer friend had the occasional problem with some of the LED stage lights pulsing. He corrected the problem by adding a fan into the circuit.  Cooled him at the light board and got rid of the pulse.

I don't understand the physics of it, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your fixtures are probably fine.  The problem is LED lamps require so little current AND they have electronics in them that act differently than typical incandescent bulbs.

Comment: I see what you’re saying. I’m curious as to why the other switches are not pulsating with the same exact fixtures.

Comment: Do your other switches have any incandescent bulbs in them.   If not, maybe it's as simple as your switch's light has gone bad and you simply need to replace it the switch.